# how to add input value from session using ajaxlink in yii

Tags: yii

I am kind of lost on how to do this in my view. 
I want to add the quantity. Right now, it adds but how do I get the input value into my ajaxlink?

My controller is using session to add.

```
<input id="quantity" type="text" value="1" class="span1">
    <div id="cart-text">
    <?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink(' Add ', 
        Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/basketAjax',array('id'=>$_GET['id'])),
        array('success'=>'function(data){...
```

controller:

```
$session=new CHttpSession;
$session->open();
    if (!isset(Yii::app()->session['cart']))
        {
            $quantity = 1;
            $session->add('cart',array(
            'product_id.'.$id=>array("id"=>$id,
                'quantity'=>$quantity)
            ));
        }
        else
        {
            $cart = Yii::app()->session['cart'];
            $array = $cart['product_id.'.$id];
            if (isset($array)){
                $array['quantity']=$array['quantity']+1;
            } else {
                $t = array('product_id.'.$id=>array("id"=>$id,'quantity'=>$quantity));
                array_push($cart,$t);
            }
            $session->add('cart', $products);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

ajaxLink will not work (from what I know), just build it the old fashion way with jquery. Your best solution is actually to put it in a form and submit the form. Something like

```
<?php 
    Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('yiiactiveform');
    $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('action'=>Yii::app()->createUrl('cart/addProduct')));?>
          <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1">
          <input type="hidden" name="Product_id" value="<?php echo $model->id;?>">
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save',CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('cart/addProduct','render'=>true)),
                         array(
                             'dataType'=>'json',
                             'type'=>'post',
                             'success'=>'function(data) {
                                if(data.status=="success"){
                                 $("#formResult").html("form submitted successfully.");
                                }
                                 else{
                                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                                $("#user-form #"+key+"_em_").text(val);                                                    
                                $("#user-form #"+key+"_em_").show();
                                });
                                }       
                            }',                    
                             )); ?>
            <?php $this->endWidget(); ?><!-- .contact -->
```

Sorry for the indenting, hard to indent properly here.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using keyup function of jquery. First set the id of link as "mylink". Compute the url by using createUrl.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$("#quantity").keyup(function(){
var url=<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/basketAjax') ?>;
 $("#mylink").attr("href","");
$("mylink").attr("href",url +$(this).val());  

});
</script>
```

Now i explain whats happening above. first i catch the event keyup on input you are using. It will be called each time you press a key on input. Now `url=<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/basketAjax') ?>;` this code is returning you the base url to your action without any parameters being passed.this line `$("#mylink").attr("href","");` will set the href of your link to " "( means nothing). Now this line   `$("mylink").attr("href",url +$(this).val());` is appending the value of the input you are getting from the input.
Remember you have to put the separator in between like

```
$("mylink").attr("href",url+"/" +"id"+"/"+$(this).val());
```

Above i have assumed that the href in your case looks like "projectname/index.php/controller/action/id/something". Thats y i have used separators in between but you can customize it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what happened to the id of the item? does my ajaxlink stay the same? there would be two ids (as you said to set id as "mylink"?

Comment: i think your above posted view code does not contain Id for ajax link. If you have set it earlier then you can use that id for jquery. You can replace this id with mylink in my posted code.

Comment: and yes the ajaxlink will remain the same because your are just changing its href not its type